# Difference between the usage of Big-Omega notation as used by Computer Scientists and Mathematicians.

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, analytic-number-theory

I was reading Hoffstein¹, page 152. They define the counter part of the famous *big-*$\mathcal{O}$ notation: the *big-*$\Omega$,

> Similarly, we say that $f$ *is big-*$\Omega$ *of g* and write,
> $$f(X)=\Omega(g(X))$$
> if there are positive constants $c$ and $C$ such that
> $$f (X) \geq cg(X) \quad\text{for all} \quad X \geq C.$$

Which reads pretty standard. But, they have a footnote saying,

> Note: Big-$\Omega$ notation as used by computer scientists and cryptographers does not mean the same thing as the big-$\Omega$  notation of mathematicians. In mathematics, especially in the ﬁeld of analytic number theory, the expression $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ means that there is a constant $c$ such that there are inﬁnitely many integers $n$ such that $f (n) \geq cg(n)$. In this book we use the computer science deﬁnition.

Errmm... buh how is that any different than what they defined as the computer scientist definition? The only thing I can imagine is that in case of the mathematician definition as noted in the footnote, the integers $n$ do not have to be consecutive whereas in the C. S. definition, $X \geq C$ are consecutive? Even then I think the C. S. definition is implied by the mathematician definition. Am I right? Or am I missing some other distinction that the book wants to make?

¹Silverman, J. H., Pipher, J., & Hoffstein, J. (2008). *An introduction to mathematical cryptography*. Springer New York.

Comment: The function $f(n) = (-1)^n$ is mathematically $\Omega(0)$, while it is not computer-scientifically $\Omega(0)$.

Comment: Right and that is because of the infinite even $n$ which don't have to be consecutive for the mathematical def. but they have to be for computer scientific one.

Comment: Exactly. Computer scientific implies mathematical, but the converse does not hold.

Comment: The Hoffstein def'n is equivalent to a "Landau big $O$", that is, $g=O(f)$.

Comment: @William, if you ahead and write out the little example with a few remarks, I'll accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math definition is that there exists some infinite subsequence $I=\{n_i:i\geq 1\}$of the natural numbers and a positive constant $c$ such that for all $n\in I,$
$$
f(n)\geq c g(n).
$$

One could have
$I=\{100,110,120,\ldots \}=\{100+10k: k\geq 0\}$
for example and a function $f(n)$ which is equal to $n^2$
when $n\in I$ and zero otherwise would satisfy this definition.

The CS definition is that there is some positive $N$ and a positive constant $c$ such that for all $n\geq N,$
$$
f(n)\geq c g(n).
$$

So if $f$ satisfies the CS definition with $N=10^{100}$ it is clear that the math definition will also be satisfied since the intersection
$$
I \cap \{n: n\geq 10^{100}\}=\{10^{100}+k:k \geq 0\}
$$
is itself an infinite subsequence of the natural numbers.

Comment: I will accept this answer if you change, "there is some positive $N < \infty$" to "there is some positive $N$..." Sorry, but comparisons with infinity have caused me quite a bit of heartache and having to relearn calculus....